# Given the expected value of the product of two Bernoulli random variables, prove that they are independent

Tags: probability-theory

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables and that $E(X*Y) = E(X) E(Y)$, prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent from each other

Solution:

Considering $P(X=1) = p$ and $P(Y=1) = q$, then $E(X) = p$ and $E(Y)=q$

$E(XY) = E(X) E(Y)= p*q$

$P(XY = 1) = P[X=1 \cap Y=1])$

$E(XY) = P(XY = 1) = P([X=1 \cap Y=1]) = p*q$

Thanks to David K for the patience of explaining this exercise.

Comment: How was $X\cap Y$ defined? If I try to think of a random variable as a set, taking the intersection with another random variable gives something that is not a random variable. So there should have been a definition specifically for this use of the "intersection" symbol. I would guess that if $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli, $X\cap Y$ is $1$ if both $X$ and $Y$ are one and $0$ otherwise. But an easier way to write that would simply be to multiply the variables together: $XY$.

Comment: This exercise comes from a test of my probability course from last year. Since the question wasn't anulled, I guess it's my fault: the question is written $E(XY)$ instead of $E(X \cap Y)$, which I blindly assumed was an intersection instead of a product...If it was $E(X*Y)$ would the problem make more sense? because I didn't know we could multiply random variables.

Comment: In the context of introductory probability, random variables typically have real-numbered values, so all kinds of operations that apply to real numbers also apply to random variables. We can add or multiply two random variables, multiply a random variable by a constant, even use a random variable as an exponent in an expression like $e^X.$ But we don't apply set operations to random variables. On the other hand, we do apply set operations to *events,* while we don't apply real operations to events (such as adding two events).

Comment: When you wrote $[X=0\cap Y=0] \cup [X=1 \cap Y=1)$, that made perfect sense because we consider $X=0$ to be an event, likewise $X=1$, $Y=0$, and $Y=1$. When you take intersections and unions of these events you get another event. In this case, $[X=0\cap Y=0] \cup [X=1 \cap Y=1]$ is the event $X=Y$. So you can legitimately take the probability of that event. The thing is, though, the event whose probability you need is the event $XY=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! So if now I understand  the problem, I need to calculate $P[XY=1]$, because $X*Y$ is a Bernoulli distribution (since it can be only equal to 1 or 0) and its expected value will be $E[XY] = P[XY=1] = P[X=1\cap Y=1] = p *q$, and then it's proved X and Y are independent, right?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to be pedantic you can also compute the probability $P[XY=0],$ but since that gets multiplied by zero in the expected value calculation it's not going to change the answer. (Anyway it's really easy to get that probability since $0$ and $1$ are the only possible values of $XY$.)

Comment: Thank you so much!